# trying to find a zip file for ANTLR

Tags: c#, antlr, directory

I'm trying to follow the steps in [this tutorial](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557075) and the files listed in step 5 (part 1) don't make sense as ther referenced zip file (DOT-NET-runtime-3.1.3.zip) is not in the listed folder (or it's equivalent in 3.2). Where did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears in the changesets but not in the source. Anyway, for anyone looking for it, [it's here](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/antlr/runtime/CSharp2/dist/DOT-NET-runtime-3.1.3.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on board to the terrible ANTLR C# tour. :)

Currently I am using this one, downloaded from ANTLR v3.1.x binaries for .NET framework on this page,

http://antlr.org/download.html

Comment: that has *part* of the files i need... It's really that bad?

Comment: I don't mean ANTLR is bad. It is cool. But unless you buy some support, I don't think it is smooth to master its toolset (for C#) and start from the very beginning. I did try, but maybe I did not try hard enough.

Comment: Yup, antlr looks cool (i was referring to getting it working with c#). Do you know what happened to those DLLs though? i can't find them, and that's what i'm looking for.